# SynchronousRequestProcessor.php(95): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)

Tags: magento2, custom, rest-api

I've created Custom Rest API endpoint which works fine on my local Magento instance but I'm getting an exception on the production server

```
"#0 [internal function]: MMA\CustomApi\Model\PayPal\Transparent\SecureTokenManager->getSecurityToken(1932)
#1 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest/SynchronousRequestProcessor.php(95): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#2 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(244): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\SynchronousRequestProcessor->process(Object(Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Request\Proxy))
#3 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#4 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#5 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#6 /home/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#7 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#8 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#9 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->___callParent('launch', Array)
#10 /home/public_html/vendor/msp/apienhancer/Plugin/AppInterfacePlugin.php(75): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#11 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): MSP\APIEnhancer\Plugin\AppInterfacePlugin->aroundLaunch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor), Object(Closure))
#12 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#13 /home/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->___callPlugins('launch', Array, NULL)
#14 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(257): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
#15 /home/public_html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#16 {main}"
```

Here is the link to my extension https://github.com/troublediehard/mma-customapi.

Any ideas what is the issue?

**UPDATE:** not sure what did change but now the problem is gone. But I'm still curious about what can lead to such an issue.